# Azure data factory extract date from $$FilePath copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am copy data from storage account to synpase, I have used $$FilePath to get filename.
Filename = CPDSERVICE_20230718.xlsx
I am trying to use one more paramter date & trying to extract date from $$FilePath.
Please guide me I need to pass 20230718 date to filedate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using this  : @replace(split($$FILEPATh,'_')[1],'.xlsx','')

Comment: Position 16 Unrecognized expression: $$FILEPATH

Comment: When I give @replace(split('$$FILEPATH','_')[1],'.xlsx','')  I got below error - The parameters and expression cannot be resolved for schema operations. Error Message: {
  "message": "ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The expression 'replace(split('$$FILEPATH','_')[1],'.xlsx','')' cannot be evaluated because array index '1' is outside bounds (0, 0) of array.."
}

Answer (score 0):

`@split('$$FILEPATH','_')[1]` tries to split the string `'$$FILEPATH'` based on the character `'_'`. Since the `'_'` is not in the string, zeroth element of the array has the entire string `'$$FILEPATH'` and there is no first element. No functions can be applied to the value of `$$FILEPATH` parameter. Workaround is to copy the file along with additional column `filename` to the staging file and then take the staging file in the lookup activity. Take the filename and apply the required functions to that column to extract the date and then copy to sink file. Below is the detailed approach.

- Take the pipeline activity and then take the copy activity to copy data from source to staging file with filename as additional column.

[image]

- Then take the lookup activity and take staging file as a dataset in lookup activity.

[image]

- Then take the copy activity and staging file as source dataset. In source settings, take the additional column `filedate` and give the expression value as, `@replace(split(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Filename,'_')[1],'.xlsx','')`.

By this way, you can extract the date from the filename.

Edit:

You can use **GetMetaData activity** to get the list of source file names and take for-each activity to copy each file into the sink. While copying the source file, take the additional column as `@replace(split(item().name,'_')[1],'.xlsx','')`. This will extract the date from the filename and copy as a new column.

Comment: This approach will be little tedious to do, first copying all the filenames and then again lookup. I used metadata -->foreach --> setvaribale 1 for filename, setvariable 2 for date -->copy activity.

Comment: We don't have option in ADF to apply  functions  on `$$FILEPATH`

Comment: What do u get from metadata? is it filename?

Comment: All the child item - childItems": [
  {
   "name": "CPDSERVICE_20230718.xlsx",
   "type": "File"
  },
  {
   "name": "CPDSERVICE_20230719.xlsx",
   "type": "File"

Comment: Then uses set variable to getdate - @replace(split(item().name,'_')[1],'.xlsx','') inside loop

Comment: Yes..this should be the approach for this case. But I think you can directly add `@replace(split(item().name,'_')[1],'.xlsx','')` this expression in additional column dynamic content, instead of storing it in a variable.

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to do so, but observing some wierd filenames so decided with variables it works fine.